# Can class in parent namespace access class that is in child namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a `Device` class that is in namespace `Proj.Devices`. Can this class access `Message` class that is in namespace `Proj.Devices.Messages`. Both classes are in the same project. I am not asking if this is possible, but whether is this a bad practice?

I think that there will be problems with cyclic references if I split this project to separate projects but otherwise is this ok?

Edit:
I have found this on [Namespace Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"A nested namespace should have a dependency on types in the containing namespace. For example, the classes in the System.Web.UI.Design depend on the classes in System.Web.UI. However, the classes in System.Web.UI do not depend on the classes in System.Web.UI.Design."

Comment: depending on situation cyclic reference can occur or not, and it is not at all wrong to inherit or refer to other name space class. One such good example is if you have to create custom control, you refer to Other namespace call system.windows.controls etc.

Answer (score 11):

I can't agree with Morbia. Namespaces are not just here for grouping, they are logic separations (components) where assemblies are concrete separations (layers and concerns).

They are also often seen as hierarchical. Philosophically, something lower in a hierarchy exists through its parent which can exist without this particular child element.

I think this is why the `Core` namespace exists nowadays. The base namespace is only the base structure / the foundations.

If a sub-namespace is used by its base namespace, you can be sure that a mutual dependency will exist in most cases : this reveals an architecture hazard.

It should be avoided because :

- Dependencies madness :

  - Mutual dependencies
  - Your base namespace can't exist without a sub-namespace
  - Everything referencing the base namespace can't exist without this sub-namespace
    and etc...
- The debug steps will be less understandable
- The stacktrace will be less understandable

If you don't care about architecture, it is not a problem. But if you are asking yourself this question, you are already thinking about writing good code -which mean with new usages incoming and not only for yourself ;)-.

This is why such practices exists to avoid high coupling :

- Interfaces
- Extensions methods
- Virtual/override

Architecture is about time and not only beauty. At a certain maturity, architecture-less code is 
less maintainable, less understandable and less scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can, namespace is just grouping of classes.
No it is not bad practice it is a normal scenario.

If classes from both namespace references each other its not good idea to have them in separate project, as long as they are in same project it is fine.

Comment: Somewhere I had read that is a bad practice and I tried to avoid such situations.  As result I think I have better organised projects. Good example is provider pattern. Concrete providers are in child namespace Pr.DevAccess.Providers, while interfaces are in Pr.DevAccess. Concrete provider can depend on types in DeviceAccess namespace but not vice versa. I try to follow these two rules:
1. Classes that are on the same namespace level that has common parent can depend on each other.
2. Classes that are in child namespace cannot depend on types in parent namespace.

Comment: Well in practical life I always end up with many sub folders for supporting functionality like Configuration, Cache, Managers, Helper etc for my main classes in the root, that sub folder will have child namespace and are used by classes in parent namespace. What you mentioned may be fine for WCL.

Comment: Sorry I mean BCL (base class library) not WCL.